# Rotation & Pinch(scale) gesture messes parent UIView and his subviews frame

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, scale

I'm trying to implement Pinch & Rotate gestures on a UIView who contains several subviews(UIButton,UITextView).
**Code organized below to your convenience**

I'm guessing i'm missing something. No idea what tho. Thank you!

Result :

[image]

**Code**

Scale :

```
 var scaleAnchorPoint = CGPoint()

    func handleSizeIncreasing(sender:UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began
        {
            print("Began")
            scaleAnchorPoint = self.center
        }

        else if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed
        {
            txtView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(txtView.transform, sender.scale, sender.scale)
            sender.scale = 1.0
            self.frame.size = CGSizeMake(txtView.frame.width + buttonSize, txtView.frame.height + buttonSize)
            self.center = scaleAnchorPoint
            updateViews(scaleAnchorPoint)
            print("Changed")
        }

    }
```

Rotate :

```
var rotateAnchorPoint = CGPoint()

func handleRotate(sender : UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {

    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began
    {
        print("Began")
        rotateAnchorPoint = self.center
    }

    else if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed
    {
        sender.view!.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(sender.view!.transform, sender.rotation)
        sender.rotation = 0
        updateViews(rotateAnchorPoint)
        print("Changed")
    }



}
```

Side:

```
 func updateViews(aroundPoint : CGPoint  )
    {
        self.center = aroundPoint
        txtView.frame.origin = CGPointMake(buttonSize / 2, buttonSize / 2)
        txtView.contentSize = txtView.frame.size
    }
    func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Simply, when the scale/frame changes, instead of accessing the `Frame` like i did here : `self.frame.size = CGSizeMake(txtView.frame.width + buttonSize, txtView.frame.height + buttonSize)`

**Access self.bounds** , like this -

```
 self.bounds.size = CGSizeMake(txtView.frame.width + buttonSize, txtView.frame.height + buttonSize)
```

Enjoy!